# Spark(2.3.1) LDA transfomation memory error(java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)

Tags: apache-spark, out-of-memory, transform, lda

I trained LDA(feature dimension : 100, iteration: 100, Distributed version , ml )  using Spark 2.3.2. After that I want to transform new DataSet by using that model. But when I transform new data, I alway get error related memory error. I changed data size from x 0.1 , to x 0.01. But always get memory error(java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)

That hugeCapacity error(overflow) is happened when size of array is over Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8. But I changed data size to small size. I can't find why this error is happened.

If you have any idea related to this, anything is welcome.

Below is code

```
val countvModel = CountVectorizerModel.load("s3://~/")
val ldaModel = DistributedLDAModel.load("s3://~/")
val transformeddata=countvModel.transform(inputData).select("productid", "itemid", "ptkString", "features")
var featureldaDF = ldaModel.transform(transformeddata).select("productid", "itemid", "topicDistribution", "ptkString").toDF("productid", "itemid", "features", "ptkString")
featureldaDF=featureldaDF.persist //this is 328 line
```

Below is my environment

DataSet

1. Document : about 100,000,000 --> 10,000,000 -->  1,000,000(All fail)
2. Word : about 3553918(can't change)

Spark environment

1. executor-memory,driver-memory : 18G --> 32g --> 64 --> 128g(all fail)
2. executor-core,driver-core : 3
3. spark.serializer : default and org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer(both fail)
4. spark.executor.memoryOverhead : 18G --> 36G fail

Jave version : 1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation)

Other testing

1. Java option :  UseParallelGC , UseG1GC (all fail)

Below is log

```
19/03/05 20:59:03 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ByteBufferOutputStream.write(ByteBufferOutputStream.scala:41)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:342)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:850)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:849)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:608)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.buildBuffers(InMemoryRelation.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.<init>(InMemoryRelation.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$.apply(InMemoryRelation.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager$$anonfun$cacheQuery$1.apply(CacheManager.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.writeLock(CacheManager.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.cacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.persist(Dataset.scala:2907)
    at coupang.cs.predictforxgboost.App$.main(App.scala:328)
    at coupang.cs.predictforxgboost.App.main(App.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
```

For @Ilya Brodezki

This is save error.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
at org.apache.spark.util.ByteBufferOutputStream.write(ByteBufferOutputStream.scala:41)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1877)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1786)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1189)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:43)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:342)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:850)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:849)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:849)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:608)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SortExec.doExecute(SortExec.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.orc(DataFrameWriter.scala:572)
at coupang.cs.predictforxgboost.App$.main(App.scala:361)
at coupang.cs.predictforxgboost.App.main(App.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many Hadoop configrations that can control or help with OOO issues but I think in your case you can just set 
sqlDF.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
so when you do a persist instead of trying to keep everything in memory It will spill extra data to the disk.
there are many different flags for persist you can also use: 
sqlDF.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
which keeps the data unserialized

Comment: This OOM is not related to persist. If I use some Dataframe's action, that OOM always happen.(Like show or save). But I will test your option.

Comment: Let me know if it helps, and if not please add the error for the failure you get in show/save

Comment: I add more log on saving dataframe

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to solve this? I get exactly the same error when I do a pca on 40.107 features. My master has 235g and the 3 executors 115g each!